# Toggle "ActionController::Parameters.action_on_unpermitted_parameters = :raise" on specific controller methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, strong-parameters

I want to use

```
ActionController::Parameters.action_on_unpermitted_parameters = :raise
```

To raise an exception unpermitted parameters are passed in, but I only want to do this on specific controller methods, instead of setting it in /config/ and having it apply to the whole environment. Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure Wasif's answer will work properly because it never sets it back. At a minimum I think you want this:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  around_action :raise_action_on_unpermitted_parameters, only: %i[create update]

  def index
    # ...
  end

  def create
    # ...
  end

  def update
    # ...
  end

  private

  def raise_action_on_unpermitted_parameters
    begin
      ActionController::Parameters.action_on_unpermitted_parameters = :raise
      yield
    ensure
      ActionController::Parameters.action_on_unpermitted_parameters = :log
    end
  end
end
```

And even then I'm not sure you won't encounter a race condition where it's set to raise on different controller actions accidentally if you're using a multithreaded server like Puma.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own Parameters class:

```rb
  class Parameters < ActionController::Parameters
    self.action_on_unpermitted_parameters = :raise
  end

  def params
    Parameters.new(super.to_unsafe_hash)
  end
```

This relies on Rails' current implementation to check `self.class.action_on_unpermitted_parameters` to determine what to do.

I prefer this solution over toggling ActionController::Parameters.action_on_unpermitted_parameters during the action because you are in control where you want your custom behaviour. Other code is not affected. But it depends on your needs. Do you want the raising behaviour *during* some controller actions or *within* the controller action code?

Answer (score -1):

**Update**: (taking inspiration from Mike's answer)

To restrict the change only for a set of controller actions and to revert it back to the original value that the class attribute was holding before the action being invoked, we can use `around_action`

```rb
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  around_action :raise_action_on_unpermitted_parameters, only: %i[create update]

  def index
    # ...
  end

  def create
    # ...
  end

  def update
    # ...
  end

  private

  def raise_action_on_unpermitted_parameters
    original = ActionController::Parameters.action_on_unpermitted_parameters
    ActionController::Parameters.action_on_unpermitted_parameters = :raise
    yield
  ensure
    ActionController::Parameters.action_on_unpermitted_parameters = original
  end
end
```