# Rails unpermitted parameters still saving the object

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, parameters

I'm making a comment form for different posts. I have a show page for my posts with a form embedded:

```
<%= @comment.body %>

<%= form_with url: comments_path do |form| %>
    <%= form.hidden_field :post_id, value: @comment.post.id %>
    <%= form.hidden_field :parent_comment_id, value: params[:id] %>
    <%= form.text_field :body %>
    <%= form.submit %>
 <% end %>
```

I then have a controller for my comments:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = current_user.comments.new(comment_params)
    @comment.post_id = @post.id

    if @comment.save!
        flash.now[:notice] = 'Comment created'
        redirect_to post_path(@comment.post_id)
    else
        raise error
    end
end

def show
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
end

def comment_params
    params.permit(:body, :post_id, :author_id)
end
end
```

The reason I don't say params.require(:comment) is because a comment isn't being passed through in my params -- I believe this is because the form is embedded in the show page for posts.

When I submit a comment, I can do so, but I get this oddity in the console:

```
Started POST "/comments" for ::1 at 2021-01-09 17:50:10 -0500
Processing by CommentsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"RblvPFQq7aZnpYFfLA5LtuUHsSDIrljYgZjs7OkvnzY4I6jhwZZXgv1+2xC1ZXdF8iDAUGQ22VPhRzHtmwHDcA==", "post_id"=>"8", "body"=>"ten", "commit"=>"Save "}
  Post Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 8], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:4:in `create'
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:6:in `current_user'
Unpermitted parameters: :authenticity_token, :commit
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:8:in `create'
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:8:in `create'
  Post Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 8], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:8:in `create'
  Comment Create (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "comments" ("body", "author_id", "post_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["body", "ten"], ["author_id", 2], ["post_id", 8], ["created_at", "2021-01-09 22:50:10.956311"], ["updated_at", "2021-01-09 22:50:10.956311"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:8:in `create'
   (0.3ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:8:in `create'
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/posts/8
Completed 200 OK in 12ms (ActiveRecord: 1.5ms | Allocations: 8098)
```

Note the "unpermitted parameters." I thought this would stop the saving of the comment, but it still goes through and saves, so I'm not sure if this is an issue that might cause later problems. I then have a show page to recursively render the comments if they have child comments. Note: all my associations between post, user, comments, and replies (self-association) are in place. Does anyone have a solution to these "unpermitted parameters"/passing a "params.require(:comment).." even when I'm not on a comment show page?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is the default action for handling `unpermitted parameters`, just logging that it happened in development and not even logging it in production. The config on how this should be handled is `action_on_unpermitted_parameters` (You can read more about it [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.0/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html)).

It is up to you if you want it to behave differently like for example to throw an error if unpermitted parameters are passed, or you can just leave it as it is as well. If you want to change it and raise an error just add this to `production.rb` or `development.rb`:

```
config.action_controller.action_on_unpermitted_parameters = :raise
```

For modifying this only for a specific controller check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47693233/toggle-actioncontrollerparameters-action-on-unpermitted-parameters-raise)